# Advanced Custom Fields : how to show the result of a front end submission in an admin email?

Tags: wordpress, email, advanced-custom-fields

On the front end, a visitor can submit an 'inquiry' post type, with several fields of different types on a multi step front end form.
At the end of the form, I want to send to the website admin email the result of this submission.

The only way I found yet is to use the acf_form( array( 'post_id' => $inquiry_id ) ); call to generate a form that I capture with ob_start/ob_get_clean and use as the email content.

However, the visual result is quite poor, as no ACF styles applies (fields width in particular), and it still looks like a form, not a form result. Optional empty fields are still displayed
[as seen on this email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJeOO.png)

Is there a way to do that without manually going through each field, hiding the empty ones, showing each with its own logic ?